# error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I am making a function that loads a file in memory in form of linked list.But when I am compiling the code the error comes namely: `error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’`

the code is below

load_file.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node{
    char* data = NULL;
    struct node* next = NULL;
};

struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* tail = NULL;

int load_file(char* file_name){

    char line[1000];
    char* data = NULL;
    struct node* temp = NULL;

    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("cannot open the file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%99s",line) == 1){
        data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));
        if(data == NULL){
            printf("could not allocate memory for string\n");
            return -2;
        }

        strcpy(data,line);

        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(temp == NULL){
            printf("could not allocate memory for node\n");
        }
        if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }else{
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

load_file.h:

```
int load_file(char*);
```

test.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"load_file.h"

int main(){

    char* file= "text.txt";

    printf("ruuning\n");
    load_file(file);
    printf("done");


    return 0;
}
```

While compiling the error comes:

```
harsh@harsh-Inspiron-3558:~/c/bank_management/include/load_file$ sudo gcc test.c load_file.c -o test
load_file.c:6:13: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
  char* data = NULL;
             ^
load_file.c: In function ‘load_file’:
load_file.c:42:8: error: ‘struct node’ has no member named ‘next’
    tail->next = temp;
        ^
load_file.c:43:15: error: ‘struct node’ has no member named ‘next’
    tail = tail->next;
               ^
```

Sorry for any mistakes. I am a beginner.

Comment: Simply because C is not C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not add initializers to the type definition; change

```
struct node{
    char* data = NULL;
    struct node* next = NULL;
};
```

to

```
struct node{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

You'd initialize those fields when you create an *instance* of `struct node`, like so:

```
struct node foo = {NULL, NULL};
```

or

```
struct node foo = { .data = NULL, .next = NULL }; // as of C99
```

or

```
struct node foo;
...
foo.data = NULL;
foo.next = NULL;
```

or

```
struct node foo;
...
foo = (struct node){.data = NULL, .next = NULL}; // as of C99
```

or

```
struct node *foo = malloc( sizeof *foo );
foo->data = NULL;
foo->next = NULL;
```

or

```
struct node *foo = malloc( sizeof *foo );
*foo = (struct node){.data = NULL, .next = NULL}; // as of C99
```

Note that while

```
struct node *foo = calloc( 1, sizeof *foo );
```

will initialize the fields of `*foo` to all bits 0, that's not necessarily the same as initializing them to `NULL` - all that's guaranteed is that a zero-valued *constant expression* is equivalent to `NULL`, not a zero-valued runtime expression.

Answer (score 2):

C structs don't have default values for members. Remove the `= NULL` from the struct definition. If you want the values to be zeroed out initially, allocate the struct with `calloc`, not `malloc`, or if it's a stack or global variable (not heap allocated), declare/initialize it as `struct node name = {0};`